# Why wont github connect with port 443 with ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I changed the .ssh config file to use port 443 and I checked that it worked:

```
bash-4.2$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi keiashford! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell 
access.`bash-4.2
```

But when trying to clone a repository using ssh over port 443?

```
bash-4.2$ git clone ssh://git@ssh.github.com/keiashford/getexorcism-ssh htdocs
Cloning into 'htdocs'...
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I cant use port 22 because im already using ssh to get into this remote computer

Comment: _"I cant use port 22 because im already using ssh to get into this remote computer"_ - TCP ports don't work like that.

Comment: 443 is standard port for https so no point in trying to use ssh through it as they are different protocols..... unless you have an ssh server listening there....  possible but.... github? No way!

Comment: When I used 'ssh -T git@github.com' with port 22 it always timed out and only worked when I altered the config file to make ssh always use port 443.

Comment: @eftshift0: GitHub have a hack where their https server checks the first few incoming bytes and dispatches to sshd or a true https server based on that, so that you *can* ssh to port 443 on GitHub.

Comment: It looks like you've mapped ports for `github.com` but not for `ssh.github.com`. It's also possible that the ssh that Git is running isn't the ssh that your CLI is running (depending on path setup).

Comment: @eftshift0 https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port , https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/ , https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/#If-port-22-is-blocked

Comment: Interesting! Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outgoing destination port 22 is filtered. Check with `sudo iptables -L OUTPUT` if you don't want to bother with the firewall or git config, you can just `git clone ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/keiashford/getexorcism-ssh htdocs`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add new a config file at `~/.ssh` if you do not have it yet, insert like below

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

After, you can run ssh -T git@github.com to confirm if the issue is fixed. The result will be

```bash
Hi xxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Hopefully, this helps you.